# Reading a text and put it in an array exactly as shown

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a .txt file like this:

```
@Override annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to 
override an element declared in a superclasses.
  // mark method as a superclass method
  // that has been overridden
   @Override 
   int overriddenMethod() { }
```

My question is, if i use a simple String can i make so it shows exactly as it's shown above or does it have to be a String array?

Comment: I've no clue what you are trying to do. Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can read into a single String using \Z delimiter to read until EOF character, java uses some [scape sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) to show spaces, slashes, etc.

```
String content;
try{
    content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("file.txt not found");
}
```